# How can we call C# method when javascript table cell onclick in MAUI webview

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

Hi I am trying to call MAUI C# method to read inner html string of Table td click event.

in Td onclick event i want to call MAUI C# method. Is it possible, Can you please help me how to do that?